# How can I center text on a vertical line in a table

Tags: tables, tabularx, alignment

I have the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
  \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XcX}
    I am the first of \newline two lines of text &
    \emph{a{\vrule height -.5em}{\hss\vrule depth -1em}nd} &
    the rules in the center should be aligned in the middle \newline
    but they are not \newline
    and it looks bad.
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

which renders as

[image]

Unfortunately:

- The vertical line is not centered over the word "and"
- There is extra space between the "a" and the "n"

I was hoping to use `\rlap` to solve these problems, but it appears to truncate the box vertically such that no rule is drawn at all.

How can I fix the two problems above?

Answer (score 3):

I used `\valign` primitive with single declared row. Each item is `\vbox` with given parameters. The vertical rule is created by `\omit` and `\leaders` TeX primitives. The word `and` is (of course) inside `\hbox to 0pt` centered by two `\hss`. This `\hbox` is between two equal `\leaders\vrule\vfill`, so it is vertically centered too.

```
\def\twocol #1#2{%
   \hbox{
      \valign{\vfil\vboxx{##}\vfil \cr
         #1\cr \omit \leaders\vrule\vfill \hbox to0pt{\strut\hss and\hss} 
                     \leaders\vrule\vfill \cr #2\cr
      }
   }%
}
\def\vboxx#1{\vbox{\hsize=.35\hsize \leftskip=2em \rightskip=2em 
             \def\\{\hfil\break} \noindent\strut #1\strut}}

\twocol{I am the first of\\ two lines of text}
       {the rules in the center should be aligned in the middle
        but they are not and it looks bad.}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what's going on with the `##` here?

Comment: `\halign{<pre>#<post>\cr item \cr item\cr}` creates one-column table, the `#` is used in the declaration part of `\halign` primitive. `\valign` is analogous to `\halign`, it creates transposed tables. And the `#` is doubled here because it is used in macro body: each `##` is interpreted as `#` and each `#1`, `#2` , ... is interpreted as the place of first parameter, second parameter etc. when TeX reads the macro body.

Answer (score 2):

With `nicematrix` (and `tikz`) you can define a new rule style that has the `and` placed on the rule.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
    andlabel/.style={
        postaction={decorate, decoration={markings, mark={at position .5 with \node[fill=white]{\itshape and};}}}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions
    {custom-line={letter=I, tikz={andlabel}, width=12mm}}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{cIc}
  \Block[l]{1-1}{I am the first of\\two lines of text} &
  \Block[l]{1-1}{the rules in the center should be\\aligned in the middle\\but they are not\\and it looks bad.}
  \end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{X[m]cX[m]}
    I am the first of \newline two lines of text &
    \emph{and} &
    the rules in the center should be aligned in the middle \newline
    but they are not \newline
    and it looks bad.
  \CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (1-2.north) -- (1-|1-2.north) ; 
    \draw (last-2.south) ++ (0,-2pt) -- (last-|1-2.south) ; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

The main goal here was to use `\raisebox` to center "and" within a vertical space, then add rules above and below.  The column itself uses `\centering` for horizontal alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}
  \savebox\tempbox{\raisebox{0.3ex}[\ht\strutbox][\dp\strutbox]{and}}% fudged to look good
  \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}%
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X>{\centering}m{\wd\tempbox}X}
    I am the first of \newline two lines of text &
    \rule{0.4pt}{1.2em}\par
    \usebox\tempbox\par
    \rule{0.4pt}{1.2em} &
    the rules in the center should be aligned in the middle \newline
    but they are not \newline
    and it looks bad.
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: These rules don't scale vertically with the content, right?

Comment: Nope.  The only way I know of to do that is measure the other columns in their own saveboxes, at which point you no longer need a tabular.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
  \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XcX}
    I am the first of \newline two lines of text &
    \newbox\mybox
    \setbox\mybox=\hbox{\strut\emph{and}}
    {\vrule height -2pt}\hspace{-\arrayrulewidth}%
    {\vrule depth -6pt}\hspace{-0.5\arrayrulewidth}%
    \hspace{-.5\wd\mybox}\box\mybox &
    the rules in the center should be aligned in the middle \newline
    but they are not \newline
    and it looks bad.
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

which uses `setbox` to save the width of the "and", and then piles on some `hspace` to overlap everything.

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

With `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/709782/how-can-i-center-text-on-a-vertical-line-in-a-table
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    [%
        enhanced,
        sidebyside,
        %colback=black!5!white,% by default
        segmentation code={%
            \draw (segmentation.north)--(segmentation.south);
            \node [fill=black!5!white,circle,inner sep=2pt]at (segmentation.center) {and};
            },     
    ]
    I am the first of
    
    two lines of text 
\tcblower
the rules in the center should be aligned in the middle \newline
    but they are not

    and it looks bad.
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]